# Unpickling error with MARK: how to solve it?

Tags: python, function, load, pickle

I am trying to load a simple list from a file to another, but python raises `_pickle.UnpicklingError: could not find MARK` as soon as I run it. The code is really simple and follows what the course tells me, I really don't understand. It goes as follows: file "donnees.py" has the list, and "fonctions.py" has the rest.

donnees.py

```
listemots=["bonjour","pivers","cactus","france","taureau","espace"]
```

fonctions.py

```
import pickle
import random

with open("donnees.py","rb") as donnees:

    unpickler1=pickle.Unpickler(donnees)

    listerecuperee=unpickler1.load()

print(listerecuperee)
```

Error raises is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sebastienchabrol/Documents/Cours de python/pendu/fonctions.py", line 6, in <module>
    listerecuperee=unpickler1.load()
_pickle.UnpicklingError: could not find MARK
```

Does someone have an idea about how to fix this ? Many thanks !!

Comment: Why not to use `import` statement instead of `pickle` to read list from `.py` file? Any specific reason?

Comment: I learnt to do it with pickle in my course...

Comment: In general, use python files are imported rather than reading as file. Your issue is, `.py` is not a pickle. You are trying to unpickle it.

Answer (score 0):

For this just use:

```
from donnees import listemotes
```

Don’t use .py files to pickle variables. If you want to persist a list then use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.